# Use the Bisection method to find solutions

Tags: numerical-methods

Use the Bisection method to find solutions, accurate to within $10^{−5}$ for the following problems. 
$$2x\cos(2x)-(x+1)^2=0,$$

for $-3\leq x\leq -2 $, and $-1\leq x\leq 0 $

Help me please. If you can help me please make sure the solution is complete and detailed so that you can understand it so that you can independently solve other examples

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Do you know what the Bisection method is?

Comment: i Know the bisection method

Comment: Then what is stopping you from using it in this example? Again, what kind of help do you need?

Comment: don't know how to implement it, if you can, then please choose, but in detail so that you can solve other examples

Comment: You implement it by doing some calculations about $20$ times for each root. How you do the calculations is up to you.

Comment: You code or copy the general bisection method `bisection(f,a,b,eps)`, then your function `my_f(x) return 2*x*cos(2*x)-pow(x+1,2)` and call `bisection(my_f,-3,2,5e-6)` and call the output your result. You might want to print out step information in the bisection method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint: Use that $$\cos(2x)=\frac{(x+1)^2}{2x}$$ and $$|\cos(2x)|\le 1$$ so $$\frac{(x+1)^2}{2|x|}\le 1$$

Comment: then ... i don't understand what to do, please help me, complete the example, i know that the formula: $\frac{b-a}{2^n}\leq 10^{-5}$

Comment: thats all, finish the problem, @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner